# NetSuite CASE WHEN not working even though all individual statements work

Tags: netsuite, case-when

I am having an issue with NetSuite's CASE WHEN in a saved search.

This works as a **Formula (Text)**:

```
CASE WHEN {type} THEN 'Kit' ELSE 'not kit' END
```

These work as **Formula (Numeric)**:

```
min(({memberitem.quantityonhand}/NULLIF({memberquantity},0))/(NULLIF({memberitem.preferredStockLevel}/NULLIF({memberquantity},0),0)))
```

and this

```
{quantityonhand}/NULLIF({preferredstocklevel},0)
```

But when I try to put them together as a Formula (Numeric) they fail:

```
CASE WHEN {type}='Kit/Package' THEN min(({memberitem.quantityonhand}/NULLIF({memberquantity},0))/(NULLIF({memberitem.preferredStockLevel}/NULLIF({memberquantity},0),0))) ELSE {quantityonhand}/NULLIF({preferredstocklevel},0) END
```

I tried having multiple CASE WHEN statements too:

```
CASE WHEN {type}='Kit/Package' 
    THEN min(({memberitem.quantityonhand}/NULLIF({memberquantity},0))/(NULLIF({memberitem.preferredStockLevel}/NULLIF({memberquantity},0),0))) 
ELSE 
    CASE WHEN {type}='Inventory Item' 
        THEN {quantityonhand}/NULLIF({preferredstocklevel},0) 
    ELSE 'nope' 
    END 
ELSE 'nope' 
END
```

Still not working.

I am thinking that the issue could be that my CASE WHEN statement is meant for Formula (Text) and my output is meant for Formula (Numeric). If that is the case, how do I check my item type in a numeric format, or is my code just wonky?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in the final example you have two `ELSE` statements in the outer `CASE`.  Also be very careful of carriage returns.  If you do use them then put in a space before every carriage return.  Are you potentially dividing by 0?

Comment: Thank @gillyspy for the notes. I have the NULLIF in there to prevent a division by zero. It basically sets the value to zero if there could be a division by zero. Yeah, I see that the final example may not work, but example 2 should work. Not sure why it isn't.

Comment: You can't mix aggregates and non-aggregates. Like in SQL things need to be in the group  by or be an aggregate function.

Comment: @BrianThank you! That worked! I posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I wanted to follow up here and post the answer that I figured out based on help in the comments.

@Brian figured out the issue and gave me the advice that I needed to get it working. He was correct - I had mixed aggregates with non-aggregates. Here is what ended up working:

```
CASE WHEN {type}='Kit/Package' THEN ({memberitem.quantityonhand}/NULLIF({memberquantity},0))/(NULLIF({memberitem.preferredStockLevel}/NULLIF({memberquantity},0),0)) ELSE {quantityonhand}/NULLIF({preferredstocklevel},0) END
```

So you can see that what worked was to remove the min() function from the kit portion. I still need to figure out how to get the correct kit inventory numbers, but @Brian's advice solved the main issue.